# SQL Server find first gap between ID key fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any other better way to perform this operation?

```
-- USE EXAMPLE: EXEC GetFirstIdInGap @tableName ='Employees',@column='IdEmployee'
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFirstIdInGap 
    (@tableName sysname, 
    @column sysname)
AS
    IF @tableName IS NOT NULL and @column IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @col varchar(50), @col2 varchar(50)
        SET @col = 'A.' + @column;
        SET @col2 = 'A2.' + @column;
        EXEC ('SELECT ISNULL((MIN('+@col+') - 1),(SELECT ISNULL(MAX('+@column+')+1,1) FROM '+@tableName+')) 
                    AS '+@column+'
                    FROM '+@tableName+' AS a
                    LEFT JOIN '+@tableName+' AS a2
                            ON '+@col2+' = '+@col+' - 1
                    WHERE '+@col2+' IS NULL AND '+@col+' > 1');
    END
GO
```

It gets the first free ID (if there are gaps) or the last one + 1 given a @tableName and @column. If there are no rows, it returns as the first ID = 1.

**UPDATE:**

For those who have asked about why do I need gaps of ID's, I am gonna explain my problem (although I didn't want to dig into it). I work with C# Winforms applications against other firmware applications which have **serious memory restrictions**. One of those restrictions is that I can only use a maximum code value of 65536. Those codes are equivalent of database ID's, and in some cases the firmware code had reached the value of 65536. That's why gap reusing would be wonderful for me.

Comment: What version of SQL Server and why do you care if your `id` columns have gaps?

Comment: you may be able to use a LAG function to see if there is a gap.  Not sure how to best compare for performance however.

Comment: @Randy - Not until next version of SQL Server I'm afraid.

Comment: Why are you looking for gaps? Resusing ids is a very bad practice! You can cause some spectacular data integrity issues that way if you didn't properly have FKs set up on all tables. You also can have issues if users are frefeing to old reports and now the db refernces a differnt record. If you have a numeric ids, use identities and don't worry about gaps unles you have some specific regulatory or legal reason not to have gaps. Users saying they don't like gaps is not enough of a reason to to do something risky, error prone and more expensive in development time and performance.

Comment: @Martin Smith - SQL Server 2008 R2. It could be very useful to reuse those gaps if the amount of rows tends to rise a lot and many of them are deleted in the future. Depending on the problematic, we could declare an Intenger ID and never reach its 2147483647 value (without using BigInt).

Comment: Well if you are doing single row inserts (which is all your procedure is good for) that is going to take a long time and this sounds like an extremely niche hypothetical situation to me. See @HLGEM's comment above.

Comment: @GoRoS you'll have many more issues from reusing those gaps, than you would for having large ids, this approach will come bite you (or others) in the future

Comment: Yes, I've read it again and is what it seems. I have apologised once again for that misunderstanding. I have just explained in my post update why did I need gap reusing for those who had doubts.

Comment: @GoRoS +1 For the explanation. Seems you are indeed in a niche situation. Of course it is nothing to do with me why you want to do this but 99.9% of the time it is a bad idea and in that kind of situation I don't supply an answer without understanding why it is needed.

Comment: @Martin Smith I agree with you. It was absolutely my fault because I did not explain my problem correctly in detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that doesn't require a numbers table (even one with more than 1,000 rows):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetFirstIdInGap_2
    @table  SYSNAME,
    @column SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N';WITH c AS
        (
            SELECT n = ' + @column + ', 
              rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @column + ')
            FROM ' + @table + '
        )
        SELECT ' + @column + ' = 1 + COALESCE(
            (SELECT MIN(c.n) FROM c INNER JOIN c AS n
            ON n.rn = c.rn + 1 WHERE n.n - c.n > 1),
            (SELECT MAX(c.n) FROM c),
            0);';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

Comment: That's brilliant @Aaron Bertrand, it works perfectly! And I guess it is much more efficient than mine, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

t is your table

```
select 
coalesce((select min(id)+1 from t mt where not exists(select 1 from t where id+1 = mt.id )), 1) firstgap
```

Answer (score 0):

`t` is your table

```
select  min(isnull(id,0)+1) from t where  isnull(id,0) + 1 not in (select isnull(id,0) from t)
```